# Showing Airy's Integral (Fourier Transform of e^{-ip^3/3}) Converges

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

Airy's integral (a.k.a. $\widehat{e^{-ip^3/3}}$ times some constant multiple) is given by 
$\displaystyle\text{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ipx}e^{-ip^3/3}dp$.

Although it looks like it should diverge at $\infty$, apparently you can use integration by parts to reduce the formula to an integral with $p^3$ in the denominator plus some obviously finite terms. (I've also heard you can reduce the formula to an integral with $p^2+1$ in the denominator.) I can't figure out how to set up the by-parts to get to that reduction. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty [(p^2+x) \exp(-i(p^3/3+px))] \frac1{p^2+x} \, dp
$$

Comment: Does that not create an issue at $x=-1$?

Comment: You mean, around $p=\pm\sqrt{-x}$?  You can put a small interval around $p=\pm\sqrt{-x}$ and integrate that separately using the original formula.